# How can I get rid of the byte-order mark ï»¿

Tags: vi, character-encoding, html

I have created an html webpage when I run it at the bottom of the page there's some unwanted characters uncoding ï»¿. I tried to get rid of it through vi using `set nobomb` but it still appears in the webpage, the file is saved as UTF8, does anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Comment: If it's saved as utf8, just delete the ï»¿. Utf8 doesn't need a BOM.

Comment: It's appearing in the webpage not in my code so I can't just delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A byte-order-mark would only be at the beginning of a file (not at the end).  You may have gotten that at the end of the file by appending a UTF-8 file to a non-UTF-8 file.

However, you can use vim for editing (and removing) the stray BOM:

```
:%s/^Vufeff//g
```

where that `^V` is <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Further reading:

- [set nobomb not removing byte oredr mark in vim](http://www.resolvinghere.com/sof/16374239.shtml)
  (misspelling is in the actual posting).